# How to declare TypeScript return type of Rx.Observable.fromPromise()

Tags: typescript, promise, rxjs, observable

I have a function returning an `Rx.Observable` created from a promise, as follows:

```
var data$ = fetchData();
fetchData() {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch("someUrl"));
}
```

In Visual Studio Code, if I hover over the variable `data$` it shows the type as `Observable<Response>`. However, if I explicitly declare the function return type as such, e.g. `fetchData(): Rx.Observable<Response> {...}` I get an error: "Cannot find name 'Response'."

It works when declaring the return type as `Observable<any>` but this is too general. How should I declare the function return type to match the `data$` type of `Observable<Response>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the fetch-api is still experimental, depending on your Typescript-Version you might not have all typings of the fetch-api available - in that case you could try to install the `@types/whatwg-fetch`-typings from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/whatwg-fetch).

`npm install @types/whatwg-fetch`

You can also follow this thread on github for future updates: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4948

Comment: My apologies, I should have mentioned that this is a Node project, so I'm using `node-fetch` for which I do have the types installed. To use `fetch` I have `import fetch from "node-fetch";` It seems I can do `import * as Response from "../node_modules/node-fetch/lib/response";` but this doesn't seem right (specifying the full path to the module) and even when doing this I still get the "Cannot find name 'Response'." error.

Comment: Try `npm install --save @types/node-fetch` and use `import {Response} from "node-fetch";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Types:

```
npm install --save @types/whatwg-fetch
```